# Does GCC support C++23 std::print?

Tags: c++, gcc, std, fmt, c++23

On CppCon 2022 was announced, that new official HelloWorld in C++ is now:

```
#include <print>

int main() {
 std::print("Hello world\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Do you know, is `std::print` available in GCC ? Maybe it needs some flag or additional library to activate?

Link to description https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print

Comment: Well, to start with you will likely need to provide the `-std=c++23` option to enable C++23 support. And you probably need a very new version of GCC for it to be supported. Perhaps you even need a pre-release of the next version of GCC. You can use [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) to test if you don't have access to a suitably new version of GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status of C++ features is tracked via their feature test macros. cppreference.com helpfully lists those. They would be `__cpp_lib_print` and `__cpp_lib_format` for `print` and `format`, respectively.

You can then search for those macros in the [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) and [Implementation Status of libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2023). Right now you will find no mention of `__cpp_lib_print` while `__cpp_lib_format` is listed but not implemented. So the answer is no.

You can check your own compiler with the [feature testing facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) of C++. An online compiler like [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) is a quick way to test most mainstream ones.

Comment: It is great idea to use online compiler. At least I stopped thinking how to install the latest version of gcc. I went through the compilers and found, that only MSVC support #include <print>, but it does not allow to use std::print() or std::println(). Looks like empty "print" header file is added as "partial support".

Comment: @Vladlen You probably have to set the correct standard version, too. This compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/o6PYjb83Y

Comment: @Vladlen that "partial support" is hilarious! :)

Answer (score 3):

No it does not support `std::print`.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) is a list of the feature availability for C++23 in GCC and other compilers.